# Don't mark something as changed when determining the value of a variable

Tags: ansible

I have the following role in my Ansible playbook to determine the installed version of [Packer](https://packer.io) and conditionally install it if it doesn't match the version of a local variable:

```
---
#  detect packer version
 - name: determine packer version
   shell: /usr/local/bin/packer -v || true
   register: packer_installed_version
 - name: install packer cli tools
   unarchive:
       src: https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/{{ packer_version }}/packer_{{ packer_version }}_linux_amd64.zip
       dest: /usr/local/bin
       copy: no
   when: packer_installed_version.stdout != packer_version
```

The problem/annoyance is that Ansible marks this step as having "changed":

[image: screenshot]

I'd like gather this fact without marking something as changed so I can know reliably at the end of my playbook execution if anything has, in fact, changed.

Is there a better way to go about what I'm doing above?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed):

> Overriding The Changed Result New in version 1.3.
>
> When a shell/command or other module runs it will typically report
> “changed” status based on whether it thinks it affected machine state.
>
> Sometimes you will know, based on the return code or output that it
> did not make any changes, and wish to override the “changed” result
> such that it does not appear in report output or does not cause
> handlers to fire:

```
tasks:

  - shell: /usr/bin/billybass --mode="take me to the river"
    register: bass_result
    changed_when: "bass_result.rc != 2"

  # this will never report 'changed' status
  - shell: wall 'beep'
    changed_when: False
```

In your case you would want:

```
---
#  detect packer version
 - name: determine packer version
   shell: /usr/local/bin/packer -v || true
   register: packer_installed_version
   changed_when: False
 - name: install packer cli tools
   unarchive:
       src: https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/{{ packer_version }}/packer_{{ packer_version }}_linux_amd64.zip
       dest: /usr/local/bin
       copy: no
   when: packer_installed_version.stdout != packer_version
```

Comment: You never want the first task to mark anything as changed, since it doesn't have the capacity to change anything.